# Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets in Mono Develop in Raspberry PI

Tags: raspberry-pi, mono, monodevelop

I've installed Mono and Mono Develop on Raspberry PI 4. When I create a project for ex. a console app, none of objects are recognized. For example says

```
"Predefined type System.Object is not defined or imported."
```

When I run the project the error as follows:

```
/home/pi/.cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/11852_1/Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB4019: The imported project "/home/pi/.cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/11852_1//Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk. (MSB4019) (TestConsole3)
```

What is wrong? What to do in order to be able to run the project?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b It is wrong to pursue on that path. Switch to VSCode and .NET Core SDK please.

Comment: With Mono Develop I could do UI programming.

Comment: You can do GUI development without a visual designer (and the web technology has already proven that). Also cross platform solutions like Uno allows you to develop GUI on Windows and then run it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the compiler from MsBuild to Xbuild and problem disappeared.

Comment: How do change from MSBuild to XBuild?